# Get the time of start of a gradle build

Tags: gradle

How to get a `Date` object representing the time of start of the build process in Gradle?

#### Some background

In a plugin I am writing, I need to store the date and time of the build in the constructed archive (it's mainly used to display the date along with build number in the title bar of the application, to make QA life easier).

I want to have the same date for multiple subprojects that are being built, so ideally I would like to just use the start of build. As a workaround, I hold the date in a static field, but it hurts my eyes. I've seen in the source that there are multiple `org.gradle.util.Clock` instances that hold such information, but I cannot find a way to retrieve one from a plugin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your plugin could just set/get a dynamic property on the root project:

```
def root = project.rootProject
if (!root.hasProperty("startTime")) {
    root.startTime = new Date()
}
// do whatever necessary with root.startTime
```

Comment: You're right; what I wanted is to have some Gradle-initialized date, because this way the timestamp used by my plugin will differ from the one used e.g. by Maven publishing task. After some digging it turns out that there is no such method in the public API, which is a pity.

Comment: Feel free to create an issue. However, I'm not sure if the Maven publishing task uses a Gradle-initialized date, or can even be made to use one (we call into Maven here).

Answer (score 5):

I've managed to retrieve the build time clock with following code:

```
Clock clock = project.gradle.services.get(BuildRequestMetaData.class).buildTimeClock
Date startDate = new Date(clock.getStartTime())
```

Still, it's far from being ideal, since it uses Gradle internal API: `getServices()` method is defined in `org.gradle.api.internal.GradleInternal` interface.

Comment: Still works with gradle 1.5. As far as I am concerned when writing plugins to a specific version of a software it is fine to depend on internals.. you just have to know that you may have to change your code to support a new version in the future

Answer (score 1):

I could not get either of the above methods to quite produce what the OP (and I) was looking for, so I came up with this `build.gradle`:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.Date

apply plugin: 'java'

def getCurrentTimestamp ()
{
  Date today = new Date ()
  SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat ("MM-dd-yyyy_hh-mm")
  return df.format (today)
}

task tar (type: Tar) {
  from 'src/'
  baseName 'sillyProject'
  classifier getCurrentTimestamp ()
  extension 'tar'
}

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // etc.
```

This produces the tar archive (i.e., when you run `$ gradle tar`) under `$projectDir/build/distributions/sillyProject-<currentTimestamp>.tar`. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: This will certainly get the time, but whenever you call "getCurrentTimestamp" the returned date will change.  It gets spookier when you use:
def myTime = getCurrentTimeStamp()

Because then everytime you reference "myTime" - it will have a different time :(
Just FYI ;)